# Debian GUI hangs when resuming after screen is locked for long time

Tags: debian, gdm3

Debian GUI hangs when resuming after screen is locked for 4-5 hours. (no username, password entry screen is shown)
I press ctrl+alt+f2 to switch to terminal console & the status of gdm3 is running. So, I restart gdm3 but the previous screen doesn't return back & I log in to another screen.

Is there a way to return to my original screen?

Comment: Same problem here! I turn on my laptop and the `splash screen` there is no login-box